# Approximate partition of unity by characteristic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ which is assumed to be complete, finite and without atoms. I would like to show the following:

> Let $v_1,  \ldots, v_n \in L^\infty(\mu)$ be given, such that $v_i \ge 0$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \equiv 1$. Then, there are measurable sets $E_{ij}$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$, such that:
>
> - $\Omega = E_{1j} \cup \ldots \cup E_{nj}$ is a disjoint partition
> - $ \chi_{E_{ij}} \stackrel\star\rightharpoonup v_i$ in $L^\infty(\mu)$ as $j \to \infty$ for all $i = 1,\ldots, n$.

Roughly speaking, we would like to approximate the partition of unity $1 = \sum v_i$ by the partition into characteristic functions $1 = \sum \chi_{E_{ij}}$.

I am pretty sure that this is possible and I think I have a messy proof in the case that $X$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure. Hence, my question is whether there is a nice and elegant proof of the above statement.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, what if you take ie $v_1=v_2=1/2 \chi_{[0,1]}$, how are you going to have (weak star?) convergence of characteristic functions onto $v_1$?

Comment: By characteristic functions you mean indicators, that equal $1$ on the set and $0$ otherwise? If yes, which kind of convergence are you talking about? Let's say, on real line $v_1 = \frac12(1 + \sin x)$ and $v_2 = 1 - v_1$, how would you construct a sequence of sets $E_{1j}$ that converge to $v_1$?

Comment: @s.harp That was my first reaction. Let $E_n=[0,1/2n]\cup[2/2n,3/3n]\cup\dots\cup[(2n-2)/2n,(2n-1)/2n]$. Then $\chi_{E_n}\to v_1$ weak*, and the characteristic function of the complement of $E_n$ converges to $v_2$.

Comment: @Ilya He's talkinng about weak* convergence in the dual of $L^1$. And he said it's a finite measure space, so we should consider $[0,1]$ istead of $\Bbb R$. That said: See my reply to s.harp's comment. It doesn't actually answer your question, but I think it should suffice to convince you that there's no problem...

Comment: This is very interesting! My first reaction was with a bogus counterexample exactly like s.harp's. Then I saw why that was not a counterexample, and seeing how it can be done in that case makes it clear, at least to me, that you assertion is correct. Regarding an "elegant" proof, I'll be in touch, or not.

Comment: Yes, this is about weak-star convergence in $L^\infty = (L^1)^\star$. And Ilya's example can be reached similarly to s.harp's, but by using intervals whose length scale locally like $v_1(x) / n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\mu$ is a non-atomic probability measure. We can assume $L^1(\mu)$ is separable: Let $B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\nu_j$, and let $L^1_B(\mu)$ be the $B$-measurable integrable functions. Then $L^1_B$ is separable, so if we prove the result for separable $L^1$ then we get sets converging weak* to $\nu_j$ in $L^1_B(\mu)^*$. Now if $f\in L^1(\mu)$ let $g$ be the conditional expectation $g=\Bbb E [f|B]$; then $\int_{E_i,j}f=\int_{E_{i.j}}g\to\int g\nu_i=\int f\nu_i$.

**Edit:** It's been pointed out that there's a problem here: $\mu|_B$ need not be non-atomic. We only need the following lemma:

**Lemma**  Suppose $(X,A,\mu)$ is a non-atomic measure space and $S\subset A$ is countable. There exists a $\sigma$-algebra $B$ with $S\subset B\subset A$ such that $(X,B,\mu)$ is non-atomic and separable.

The lemma "must" be true, and "can't" be all that hard. A possible proof is at the bottom of this post; for now we proceed assuming the lemma holds:

So assume $\mu$ is a non-atomic probability measure *such that* $L^1(\mu)$ is separable:

There exists a countable collection of simple functions dense in $L^1$. So there exist countably many measurable sets $A_j$ such that the span of the characteristic functions of the $A_j$ is dense. So it's enough to show there exist sets $E_{i,j}$ such that $$\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu(A_k\cap E_{i,j})=\int_{A_k}\nu_i$$for every $k$.

Let $B_N$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A_1,\dots,A_N$. Since $B_N$ is a finite $\sigma$-algebra there exists a finite partition $F_N$ of $X$ such that the elements of $B_N$ are precisely the unions of subsets of $F_N$. Choose $E_{i,N}$ in such a way that for every $S\in F_N$ we have $$\mu(S\cap E_{j,N})=\int_S\nu_j.$$Then for every $k$ we actually have
$$\mu(A_k\cap E_{i,j})=\int_{A_k}\nu_i\quad(j>k)$$since if $j>k$ then $A_k$ is a union of the elements of $F_j$.

---

The following is either a proof of the lemma or not.

Say a collection of sets $T$ is *divisible* if for every $E\in T$ there exist $E_0,E_1\in T$ such that $E_j\subset E$, $E_0\cup E_1=E$, $E_0\cap E_1=\emptyset$, and $\mu(E_j)=\mu(E)/2$. For every $E\in A$ choose a partition $(E_L,E_R)$ into two sets of measure $\mu(E)/2$.

In general let $a(T)$ be the algebra generated by $T$ and let $$d(T)=T\cup\{E_L,E_R:E\in T\}.$$Say $S=S_0$ is as in the lemma, and define $$S_{n+1}=a(d(S_n)).$$ Let $$S_\omega=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty S_n.$$Then $S_\omega$ is a countable divisible algebra.

Let $B$ be the collection of all $E\in A$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $F\in S_\omega$ with $$\mu(E\Delta F)<\epsilon.$$Then $B\subset A$ is a separable $\sigma$-algebra containing $S$, and for every $E\in B$ there exists $E'\in  B$ with $E'\subset E$ and $$|\mu(E)/2-\mu(E')|<2\epsilon,$$so $(X,B,\mu)$ is non-atomic.

Comment: This is an elegant proof!

Comment: And there's a new and improved version...

Comment: I have found an error in your reduction approach: the reduced measure $\mu|_B$ may fail to be non-atomic. This can be easiest seen by considering $v_1 = v_2 \equiv 1/2$, thus $B = \{\emptyset, X\}$. However, I am mostly interested in the separable case.

Comment: @gerw Oops... Ok,I should probably think it over for a while before rushing into print, but tell me what you think of the following attempted fix: We start with the countably many sets of the form $E=\{\nu_k>r\}$ for rational $r$. For each such $E$ we throw in a partition $E_0,E_1$ of $E$ into two sets of measure $\mu(E)/2$. And for $j=0,1$ we throw in a partition $E_{j,0},E_{j,1}$ of $E_j$ into two sets of measure $\mu(E_j)/2$. Etc. Now let $B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all those sets... ? Offhand I don't see a problem.

Comment: @gerw What about complements, you ask. Seems like there must be a fix obtainable by just adding enough sets to make things non-atomic. Version 2: Let $A$ be the (countable) algebra generated by the sets $\{\nu_k>r\}$ for rational $r$. Throw in a "dyadic partition" of each set in $A$, and consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all _those_ sets. (Or something like that...)

Comment: @gerw V 3.0: See edit...

Comment: I think there is still some issue with the possible proof of the lemma: $S_\omega$ might fail to be a $\sigma$-algebra: Start with $S_0 = \{[0,1)\}$ and choose $d$ by division of the intervals. Then, $S_\omega$ will contain $[0,2^{-n})$, but not $\{0\}$. This issue, however, is eliminated by your final step. I will think over this lemma if I have some more time.

Comment: @gerw Certainly $S_\omega$ may fail to be a $\sigma$-algebra! I didn't say it _was_ a $\sigma$-algebra, just that it's a countable divisible algebra.